# How do I set the correct path in the jQuery script?

Tags: jquery-ui, href

Dear all... I've been creating my website on another PC. Now I want to copy all PHP and jQuery files to my notebook... but all jQuery widgets does not show. How do I put the correct address in my script??

```
<link href="js/jquery.ui.all.css" rel=.....>
```

The files are at:

```
local disc(c:)/xampp/htdocs/js/jquery.ui.all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's under the web root, just add a `/` before the path to make it absolute, like this:

```
<link href="/js/jquery.ui.all.css" rel=.....>
```

Then you put a path that's not fully qualified or absolute, it's *relative to the page*, so for example your current `<link>` would only work on a page in the root folder as well, for example:

```
 /xampp/htdocs/page.html
```

With it absolute, it won't matter how deep the page is, it's looking for like this, regardless of the page path:

```
http://www.mysite.com/js/jquery.ui.all.css
```